# Define length-prefixed const wide string in C

Tags: c, string, macros

For an embedded system with USB Mass Storage (STM32 with usbd_msc library from ST), I need to define a bunch of length-prefixed string, in wide char array (2 bytes per char).

The strings identifiers to be sent to the lower layers are defined like this:

```
#define USB_INT_STR      "MSC_Interface"
```

And currently, the application example provided by ST make use of of a [formating function](https://github.com/LonelyWolf/stm32/blob/fda5947fb56139f280d232e7ec022cfb473de6ff/cube-usb-cdc/usbd/usbd_ctlreq.c#L432), to a static buffer.

As theses non standard strings are contant, I would like to have them compile time defined wide char array such as:

```
const wchar_t USB_INT_STR_pre[] = {sizeof(USB_INT_STR)*2 , 'M','S','C','_','I','n','t','e','r','f','a','c','e','\0'};
```

This way I could save up to 0x100 bytes of RAM, as in the library, a static buffer is used in a callback to format the regular string to a length prefixed wide char string.

Does any macro guru know how to put it down with a macro without splitting all my strings to wchar_t array manually?

For the technical savvy, here is the source:[usbd_desc.c source code](https://github.com/LonelyWolf/stm32/blob/master/cube-usb-msc/msc/usbd_desc.c#L151), where USBD_GetString() is called, to format string in unicode, in a USBD_StrDesc[] static buffer.

Edit: I dont think there is a solution, macro-wise, I'll then end up defining manually the string as:

```
#define USBD_INTERFACE_FS_STRING      "MSC_Interface"
const uint16_t  USBD_INTERFACE_FS_STRING_UNICODE[] = {(sizeof(USBD_INTERFACE_FS_STRING) * 2 + (USB_DESC_TYPE_STRING << 8)), 'M', 'S', 'C', '_', 'I', 'n', 't', 'e', 'r', 'f', 'a', 'c', 'e'};
```

Comment: I would think you could use something like this when declaring `#define USB_INT_STR L"MSC_Interface"` then using the macro below
`const wchar_t* USB_INT_STR_pre[] = USB_INT_STR;`

Comment: A structure would take up the same space as your cobbled array, and be easier to use. Also, are you trying to store the number of bytes or the number of wide characters in the string?

Comment: Yes, in the USB stack, device description is unicode, 2 bytes wide char, starting with length of the buffer. A structure would do, but I've multiple string of different length.

Comment: `sizeof(USB_INT_STR)*2` includes the NUL terminator. But maybe you intended that.

Comment: Is there some reason that `#define USB_INT_STR L"MSC_Interface"` won't accomplish what you're after?

Comment: Do the functions in the USB library require this sort of array?

Comment: Is this for Windows' COM? You would need `BSTR` for that

Comment: @rici: yes, it's intendend: the library take a mix of unicode with prefixed length and null terminated string.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield: L"" macro is fine for regular wide char, but here I need it to be length prefixed.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: All my program and the USB lib is in C, I prefer to stick with plain old gnu99 .

Comment: I do not think that `wchar_t` and `L""` are a portable solution.  You probably want USB descriptor strings, which are consisting of little-endian, 2 byte sized characters.  There are no guarantees about endianess or size of `wchar_t` and `L""`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with preprocessor macros. The preprocessor can concatenate tokens, but a string literal is just another token and the preprocessor is unaware of its size or elements. I see two preprocessor-only options:

- **Pass the length and string literal**, the preprocessor could make a 1-character string consisting of the length: Something akin to `L"\x001C" L"MSC_Interface"`. This need the length to be passed, because sizeof isn't available at preprocessor time. However, I'm guessing one of the things you're trying to achieve here is to deduce the length
- **Specify the string as comma-separated characters**. The macro generate something like `{ sizeof(wchar_t)*sizeof({'M','S','C','_','I','n','t','e','r','f','a','c','e','\0'}), 'M','S','C','_','I','n','t','e','r','f','a','c','e','\0'}`. The sizeof functions are left in the preprocessed code, and evaluated by the compiler later in the compilation. This however, won't exactly look pretty and will probably be confusing for someone new to the codebase.

So neither will, I suspect, achieve your objective.

I asked in a comment regarding C++, because with one file compiled as C++, you can probably do this at compile-time, and it will be usable by the rest of your C codebase. Otherwise, I think you'll be limited to hand-inserting it or generating the file that defines the descriptors to automate the process